# Is there any harm in sharing apk of my android application?

Tags: android

I run an App on my android phone by pushing it thru Android Studio. After which I use an application called "App Extractor" to get apk of my app, and later send this apk to my friends or even upload apk online.
Is there any harm in it ?

Comment: Why not just share the APK from your development machine?

Comment: If you don't want anyone but yourself to install your app, then yes there is harm, otherwise no not really

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the app extractor to make an apk. You can directly use the apk file in

> app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk

and rename it as you like

If you are concerned about the **reverse engineering** of your apk, then you should read about **proguard** which obfuscates the code and remove unused classes and methods and make it hard to reverse engineer the app

Otherwise, there is **no harm in spreading your apk**

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
But why to share your  APK from your development machine ?

**for security of your code**

There are tools available in the market to extract code from .apk file. if you are implementing pro-guard then it's okay because it will encrypt your code but than also it will not fully decrypted(will take time).